# Get name of username with SpringSecurity and JSP

Tags: spring-security, jstl

I wonder how to get the username by springsecurity, for example, my user table looks like this:

username - password - name

Authentication is done by the username + password, if I use these two options:

```
<%= request.getUserPrincipal().getName() %>
<%= SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication().getName() %>
```

He will show me the username value, but in case my username is a value personal document, so I would only show the value of the field name.

Is how to do this? I'm using JSP + JSTL. Thank you.

Answer (score 5):

You can use the spring security JSTL tags :

```
<%@ taglib prefix="sec" uri="http://www.springframework.org/security/tags" %>
```

and put in your JSP code the following code :

```
<sec:authentication property="principal.username" />
```

you will have acess to all Principal properties .